# Regex to compare 2 dates in javascript

Tags: regex

is there a good regex expression that would be able to compare two dates 
like 3/27/2010 to 3/8/2010 to tell if the first date is greater then the second date?

I'd like to compare using javascript

Comment: why don't you convert the string to a date object and then compare the two dates?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (new Date("3/27/2010") < new Date("3/8/2010")) {
   alert("something's wrong.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is almost impossible, and completely insane, to do this with a regular expression.

Instead, use Javascript's `Date` object:

```
if (new Date(str1) > new Date(str2))
```